# Google Sign In API does not work when debugging on device

Tags: android-studio, google-signin

Currently I have google's signin API working flawlessly through the Android Studio Debugger, and when I install the APK onto my Samsung S6.  But when I try to debug connected via USB, GoogleSignInResult.isSuccess() always returns false.

This is mildly infuriating because I need to debug another feature that appears to work just fine when debugging through Android studio but not on my device and i'm unable to get past my login screen. -_-

Here is the block of code that fails, and i can provide more chunks of code if needed.

```
// [START handleSignInResult]
private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);

        myIntent.putExtra("account", acct);
        startActivity(myIntent);
        finish();
    }
}
// [END handleSignInResult]

// [START signIn]
private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}
// [END signIn]

// [START onActivityResult]
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }
}
// [END onActivityResult]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you get to know the solution?